# How to rebuild an array from an existing one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects.

```
let data = [
  {
    "categories" : [
      {
        "products" : [
          {
            "name" : "Product 1"
          }
        ],
        "id" : 1369
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I'd like to rebuild it like this:

```
let data = [
  {
    "products" : [
      {
        "name" : "Product 1"
      }
    ],
    "id" : 1369
  }
];
```

If I use .map(), I get array in array with object:

```
let data = [
  [
    {
      "products" : [
        {
          "name" : "Product 1"
        }
      ],
      "id" : 1369
    }
  ]
];
```

What the solution I must apply in this case?

Comment: Try this `data = data[0].categories`

Comment: what if data or data[n].categories has two or more elements? What do you want then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [{"categories":[{"products":[{"name":"Product 1"}],"id":1369}]}];

const result = [].concat(...data.map(o => o.categories));

console.log(result);
```

Or use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with `Array.concat()`:

```js
const data = [{"categories":[{"products":[{"name":"Product 1"}],"id":1369}]}];

const result = data.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(o.categories), []);

console.log(result);
```